Desperate issue with unresponsive registrar
I do not even know who to contact for help with this issue. Please bear
with me... I did contact ICANN and the FTC but no responses yet.
The registrar I have several business domains with, DNBUY.com, has been
unresponsive for several months now. Crickets. I have used this registrar for many
years and this is the first time they have been this unresponsive.
A couple weeks ago I received an automated message that my credit card was unable to
be processed for a domain that was expiring. I was able to login but was unable to change my payment information, and only received a very cryptic error message on the page that was
unrelated to what was being managed.
This week, my normal login credentials are apparently no longer valid, and I cannot reset a
password or in any way access my account.
For several months I have left messages on their site but with no response whatsoever.
There is no email, company address or any other means to contact them other than
the online contact form.
I am more than a little concerned about being able to maintain my domains OR how I can get an accredited registrar to take over if DNBuy is defunct.
I can't even tell IF they are defunct.

Related: Unresponsive registrar

Maybe Try reaching out to https://www.enom.com/ -  The domainname dnbuy.com is registered through ENOM, and per their terms and conditions  Registration agreement they are a reseller for enom.
Their reseller policy/terms and conditions  (which is, I expect, mandated by ENOM) states

As a reseller for eNom inc. DNBuy adheres to the following and all
other legal documents found HERE (ADD HYPERLINK
TO:https://www.enom.com/terms/).

And includes the following under the "Transfers" section which states (bolding mine):

To transfer your domain name(s) you should first login to your Account
to lock or unlock your domain name(s) and/or to obtain the EPP
"AuthCode" which is required to transfer domain services in an EPP
registry (such as .org). Alternatively, you should contact your
Primary Service Provider to have your domain name(s) services locked
or unlocked or to obtain the EPP "AuthCode." If your Primary Service
Provider is unresponsive, you may contact us to have your domain
name(s) locked or unlocked or to obtain the EPP "AuthCode" though we
may first contact your Primary Service Provider to request that the
Primary Service Provider address the request. Only the registrant and
the administrative contacts listed in the WHOIS information may
approve or deny a transfer request.

If you can get it - once you have the EPP code, you can transfer the domain to another provider, although you may need to rebuild the DNS zone file.

In this situation, you should take the following steps:
Contact ICANN: You've already reached out to ICANN, which is the right move. If you haven't received a response, try sending another request and emphasize the urgency. ICANN oversees accredited registrars and can help you, especially if your registrar is unresponsive.
Consider Legal Action: If DNBUY.com remains unresponsive and you can't access your domains, consult a lawyer who specializes in internet law. You might need to send a formal letter or even consider legal action to resolve the issue.

@SweetCatty Why would going to ICANN be correct when the domain is with an ENOM reseller and the terms and conditions of both ENOM and the reseller say to reach out to ENOM in the first instance?  ICANN resources specifically say they don't deal with this - https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/lost-domain-names/
